# What is a formula for symmetrical placement of P points on an NxN grid?

Tags: functions

I'm working on a game that has an arbitrary square grid size of n by n (where n > 20). In the game you can have y players (where y is between 1 and 10).

At the start of the game, I would like to place each player in a spot on the grid that is roughly symmetrical with the other players. I don't have any real constraints about proximity to the outside or the inside of the grid, so long as they players all start in equal(ish) position.

In this game players will be trying to expand to take up as much space as possible, so it would be a disadvantage for one player to be closer to the outside of the grid or closer to more players than others.  I can - however - compensate for the disadvantage by other means (i.e. a handicap of sorts) so long as I can quantify the closeness to the edge or the average distance to other players.

Any ideas what a good function for f(n,y) = integer grid position (where n = the width/height of the grid and y is the number of players)?

This is my first mathematics question so please be gentle :)

Comment: The answer really depends on how you quantify "equalish"? If, for example, it's important that all players be roughly equidistant from the center, but it doesn't matter how close they are are to the outside of the square, a natural choice is place the players roughly in a large circle centered at the middle of the square, say, placing the $k$th player at $([n \cos (2 \pi k / y)], [n \sin (2 \pi k / y)])$, where for $z \in \Bbb R$ the symbol $[z]$ denotes the integer closest to $z$.

Comment: I assume that be 'equalish' you mean that all players would have about as 'good' of a start position in terms of winning the game; that no one would have an immediate advantage in the game pver anyone else. But that is kind of hard to determine wihtout knowing a little more about the game and how it is played... Maybe you should tell us a little more about the object of the game

Comment: @Travis and Bram28 I added some more context per your suggestions. Travis, I may need a little extra explanation of that formula :P

Comment: @Travis Do you want to turn your comment into an answer? I'd be happy to accept it at this point as i think it's the right one.

Comment: @jakejgordon I don't think my suggestion is very suitable given the constraints. Like Bram28 says in their comment, a useful suggestion would probably need to know more about the game. If it's possible, you could eliminate most of the asymmetry across players by starting with a circular grid.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up going with the circle overlaid on the grid, as suggested by @Travis. Here is the actual Elixir code I ended up writing, which is fairly easy to follow (I think). The end result is an x/y coordinate

```
#random_0_to_360_offset is just a random number of degrees (between 0 and 360) to offset each player around the circle
def get_start_cell_index(grid_size, number_of_players, player_number, random_0_to_360_offset) do
    guaranteed_margin = 8
    radius = (grid_size - 2 * guaranteed_margin)/2
    tau = 2 * :math.pi()
    radians_between_players = tau/number_of_players
    random_radians_offset = tau * random_0_to_360_offset / 360
    player_radians = radians_between_players * player_number + random_radians_offset

    x = radius * :math.cos(player_radians)
    y = radius * :math.sin(player_radians)
    {x, y}
end
```

*Note: the fact that some players will still have a slight advantage based on where they are will be compensated for in other ways in the game. This is truly good enough for my application.